# fluent map one to many

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, one-to-many

```
Class Person  
{  
   int ID;
   IList<Cat> cats;  
}  

Class Cat  
{  
   int OwnerId;
}
```

how to map person cats on nhibernate fluent?

probably stupid question but i cant find the answer..

thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
   Id(p => p.ID);
   HasMany(p => p.Cats);
}
```

Assuming you have a Cats property in there somewhere of course.

Comment: Was this the answer you were looking for? If so, please mark it as such, if not indicate as such so that other people can chip in.  Cheers S